# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'liferaySessionFactory' is defined

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, liferay

I try to run a Spring project using JUnit, I wrote all beans in a file called `application-context.xml`!
The problem appears when I run the project and the program looks for `beanDefinition` variable and finds it empty...
I'm using `FileSystemXmlApplicationContext` to define my application context and I'm unable to `loadBeanDefinitions` using this stuff! After looking on internet I found that there is a method called `loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader xmlBeanDefinitionReader)`and I don't know if this one can instantiate it or not? And how I can use it, by the way?
thanks 
and here is some code
            context=new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"classpath:application-Context.xml"}){

```
            @Override
            protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
                super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
                reader.loadBeanDefinitions("liferay-config.xml");

            }
        };
```

liferay-config.xml

```
    <bean id="liferaySessionFactory" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.spring.util.SpringFactoryUtil" factory-method="newBean">
    <constructor-arg value="com.liferay.portal.dao.orm.hibernate.PortletSessionFactoryImpl" />
    <constructor-arg>
        <map>
            <entry key="dataSource" value-ref="DataSource" />
        </map>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

note: the DataSource is already declared in the application-Context.xml

Comment: Can you post your code and you context file please.

Comment: And the complete stack trace!

Comment: Why don't you use `context=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] {"application-Context.xml", "liferay-config.xml"}){` and without `initBeanDefinitionReader()`?